# About else statements (java)

Tags: java

So first, the question as follows:
Write a program that prompts the user to enter a Social Security number in the format DDD-DD-DDDD, where D is a digit. Your program should check whether the input is valid. Here are sample runs:

```
Enter a SSN: 232-23-5435

232-23-5435 is a valid Social Security Number.
```

Another test:

```
Enter a SSN: 23-23-5435

23-23-5435 is an invalid Social Security Number.
```

My code as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SSN {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter a Social Security Number in the format DDD-DD-DDDD: ");
    String ssn = input.nextLine();

    boolean correct = true;

    if (ssn.length() != 11) {
      correct = false;
    } else {
      if (!('0' <= ssn.charAt(0) && ssn.charAt(0) <= '9')) {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (!('0' <= ssn.charAt(1) && ssn.charAt(1) <= '9')) {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (!('0' <= ssn.charAt(2) && ssn.charAt(2) <= '9')) {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (ssn.charAt(3) != '-') {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (!('0' <= ssn.charAt(4) && ssn.charAt(4) <= '9')) {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (!('0' <= ssn.charAt(5) && ssn.charAt(5) <= '9')) {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (ssn.charAt(6) != '-') {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (!('0' <= ssn.charAt(7) && ssn.charAt(7) <= '9')) {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (!('0' <= ssn.charAt(8) && ssn.charAt(8) <= '9')) {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (!('0' <= ssn.charAt(9) && ssn.charAt(9) <= '9')) {
        correct = false;
      }
      if (!('0' <= ssn.charAt(10) && ssn.charAt(10) <= '9')) {
        correct = false;
      }
    }

    if (correct == true) {
      System.out.println(ssn + " is a valid Social Security Number.");
    } else {
      System.out.println(ssn + " is an ivalid Social Security Number.");
    }
  }
}
```

This is a correct answer after asking my professer, though.

However, I still don't understand why I need the `else{}` between the bunch if statements.

If I take the `else{}` away, it works for correct SSNs, but when i enter something invalid, returns:

```
Please enter a Social Security Number in the format DDD-DD-DDDD: sd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at SSN.main(SSN.java:22)
```

What's the matter? Why do i need a `else` there? Doesn't the program just check every if statements and give the output in the end by checking if `correct` is correct of false?

I mean, even without the else, even though there are more calculations, but shouldn't it work the same?

I'm confused what went wrong, please help, thanks!

Comment: If the wrong format is entered then it will sometimes give an out of bounds exception because some parts may he missing. Use a regex and look into else if statements

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you used a loop: inside the loop, check if you're at position 3 or 6, and use that to decide whether to look for a `-` or a digit.

Comment: If not regex at least loop over the string instead of all that unsightly, hard to maintain, repetition.

Comment: `if(correct == true){` => `if (correct){`. Don't compare explicitly to booleans, you'll get it wrong and accidentally assign instead.

Comment: instead of checking each character use a simple regex like:    ssn.matches.("\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d")

Comment: @RyanZink Does that return a boolean true if it's matched?

Comment: yeah @JavaLearner check out http://regexr.com. its a great place to try out regular expressions!

Answer (score 0):

First `if` checks if input has correct lenght. If not it won't check other conditions.

If you remove `else`, then all conditions will be checked. So if you have 5 length input you get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` while accessing sixth char.

You can use `Pattern.compile(regex)` and then check if regex matches your input instead of writing such a `unclean code ifs`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to read a character that doesn't exists. If your input String is shorter than 9 characters the following code will throw an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
ssn.charAt(8)
```